# Multi-GPU training of AllenNLP coreference resolution

Tags: python, pytorch, allennlp

I'm trying to replicate (or come close) to the results obtained by the [End-to-end Neural Coreference Resolution](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D17-1018) paper on the [CoNLL-2012 shared task](http://conll.cemantix.org/2012/introduction.html). I intend to do some enhancements on top of this, so I decided to use [AllenNLP's `CoreferenceResolver`](http://conll.cemantix.org/2012/introduction.html). This is how I'm initialising & training the model:

```py
import torch
from allennlp.common import Params
from allennlp.data import Vocabulary
from allennlp.data.dataset_readers import ConllCorefReader
from allennlp.data.dataset_readers.dataset_utils import Ontonotes
from allennlp.data.iterators import BasicIterator, MultiprocessIterator
from allennlp.data.token_indexers import SingleIdTokenIndexer, TokenCharactersIndexer
from allennlp.models import CoreferenceResolver
from allennlp.modules import Embedding, FeedForward
from allennlp.modules.seq2seq_encoders import PytorchSeq2SeqWrapper
from allennlp.modules.seq2vec_encoders import CnnEncoder
from allennlp.modules.text_field_embedders import BasicTextFieldEmbedder
from allennlp.modules.token_embedders import TokenCharactersEncoder
from allennlp.training import Trainer
from allennlp.training.learning_rate_schedulers import LearningRateScheduler
from torch.nn import LSTM, ReLU
from torch.optim import Adam


def read_data(directory_path):
    data = []
    for file_path in Ontonotes().dataset_path_iterator(directory_path):
        data += dataset_reader.read(file_path)
    return data


INPUT_FILE_PATH_TEMPLATE = "data/CoNLL-2012/v4/data/%s"
dataset_reader = ConllCorefReader(10, {"tokens": SingleIdTokenIndexer(),
                                       "token_characters": TokenCharactersIndexer()})
training_data = read_data(INPUT_FILE_PATH_TEMPLATE % "train")
validation_data = read_data(INPUT_FILE_PATH_TEMPLATE % "development")

vocabulary = Vocabulary.from_instances(training_data + validation_data)
model = CoreferenceResolver(vocab=vocabulary,
                            text_field_embedder=BasicTextFieldEmbedder({"tokens": Embedding.from_params(vocabulary, Params({"embedding_dim": embeddings_dimension, "pretrained_file": "glove.840B.300d.txt"})),
                                                                        "token_characters": TokenCharactersEncoder(embedding=Embedding(num_embeddings=vocabulary.get_vocab_size("token_characters"), embedding_dim=8, vocab_namespace="token_characters"),
                                                                                                                   encoder=CnnEncoder(embedding_dim=8, num_filters=50, ngram_filter_sizes=(3, 4, 5), output_dim=100))}),
                            context_layer=PytorchSeq2SeqWrapper(LSTM(input_size=400, hidden_size=200, num_layers=1, dropout=0.2, bidirectional=True, batch_first=True)),
                            mention_feedforward=FeedForward(input_dim=1220, num_layers=2, hidden_dims=[150, 150], activations=[ReLU(), ReLU()], dropout=[0.2, 0.2]),
                            antecedent_feedforward=FeedForward(input_dim=3680, num_layers=2, hidden_dims=[150, 150], activations=[ReLU(), ReLU()], dropout=[0.2, 0.2]),
                            feature_size=20,
                            max_span_width=10,
                            spans_per_word=0.4,
                            max_antecedents=250,
                            lexical_dropout=0.5)

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    cuda_device = 0
    model = model.cuda(cuda_device)
else:
    cuda_device = -1

iterator = BasicIterator(batch_size=1)
iterator.index_with(vocabulary)
optimiser = Adam(model.parameters(), weight_decay=0.1)
Trainer(model=model,
        train_dataset=training_data,
        validation_dataset=validation_data,
        optimizer=optimiser,
        learning_rate_scheduler=LearningRateScheduler.from_params(optimiser, Params({"type": "step", "step_size": 100})),
        iterator=iterator,
        num_epochs=150,
        patience=1,
        cuda_device=cuda_device).train()
```

After reading the data I've trained the model but ran out of GPU memory: `RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 4.43 GiB (GPU 0; 11.17 GiB total capacity; 3.96 GiB already allocated; 3.40 GiB free; 3.47 GiB cached)`. Therefore, I attempted to make use of multiple GPUs to train this model. I'm making use of Tesla K80s (which have 12GiB memory).

I've tried making use of AllenNLP's [`MultiprocessIterator`](https://allenai.github.io/allennlp-docs/api/allennlp.data.iterators.html#multiprocess-iterator), by itialising the `iterator` as `MultiprocessIterator(BasicIterator(batch_size=1), num_workers=torch.cuda.device_count())`. However, only 1 GPU is being used (by monitoring the memory usage through the `nvidia-smi` command) & got the error below. I also tried fiddling with its parameters (increasing `num_workers` or decreasing `output_queue_size`) & the `ulimit` (as mentioned by [this PyTorch issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/973#issuecomment-345088750)) to no avail.

```
Process Process-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/data/iterators/multiprocess_iterator.py", line 32, in _create_tensor_dicts
    output_queue.put(tensor_dict)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/data/iterators/multiprocess_iterator.py", line 32, in _create_tensor_dicts
    output_queue.put(tensor_dict)
  File "<string>", line 2, in put
  File "<string>", line 2, in put
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 772, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 772, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 228, in serve_client
    request = recv()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/reductions.py", line 276, in rebuild_storage_fd
    fd = df.detach()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 58, in detach
    return reduction.recv_handle(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 182, in recv_handle
    return recvfds(s, 1)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 161, in recvfds
    len(ancdata))
RuntimeError: received 0 items of ancdata
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also tried achieving this through [PyTorch's DataParallel](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#dataparallel), by wrapping the model's `context_layer`, `mention_feedforward`, `antecedent_feedforward` with a custom `DataParallelWrapper` (to provide compatibility with the AllenNLP-assumed class functions). Still, only 1 GPU is used & it eventually runs out of memory as before.

```
class DataParallelWrapper(DataParallel):
    def __init__(self, module):
        super().__init__(module)

    def get_output_dim(self):
        return self.module.get_output_dim()

    def get_input_dim(self):
        return self.module.get_input_dim()

    def forward(self, *inputs):
        return self.module.forward(inputs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging through the code I found out that AllenNLP does this under the hood directly through its [Trainer](https://allenai.github.io/allennlp-docs/api/allennlp.training.trainer.html#allennlp.training.trainer.Trainer). The `cuda_device` can either be a single `int` (in the case of single-processing) or a `list` of `int`s (in the case of multi-processing):

> `cuda_device` : `Union[int, List[int]]`, optional (default = -1)
>   An integer or list of integers specifying the CUDA device(s) to use. If -1, the CPU is used.

So all GPU devices needed should be passed on instead:

```py
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    cuda_device = list(range(torch.cuda.device_count()))
    model = model.cuda(cuda_device[0])
else:
    cuda_device = -1
```

Note that the `model` still has to be manually moved to the GPU (via `model.cuda(...)`), as it would otherwise try to use multiple CPUs instead.